# how to read all text files in a directory and output as links to a html page

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to read all the txt files in a directory and output them as links on a single html page. When I open the html page, txt files should display as links. When I click on the link, the content in the txt file should open on the html page. Here is my code in perl.

```
my $dir = '/';               ## rem trailing slash
my $body;                    ## our file list
my $saveFile = '/dev/null';  ## file to save links

opendir( MYDIR, $dir ) or die 'opendir';
$body =
   join( "\n",                           ## make it legible
      map  { '<a href="$_">$_</a><br>' } ## format each file
      sort { $a cmp $b }                 ## sort them
      grep { ! /^\./ }                   ## no .name files
      grep { -T "$dir$_ }                ## only text files
      readdir MYDIR
   );
closedir MYDIR;

## build your link page
## using $body
open( FILE, $saveFile ) or die 'open';
print FILE <<EOF;
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>My Files</TITLE>
<BODY>
$body
</BODY>
</HTML>
EOF
close FILE;
```

Code to retrieve text file and I'm executing this code from the terminal as "perl showtxtfiles.pl > somefile.html" which retrieves all the txt files in the folder and displaying them on a html page. But, all I need is to show each txt file as a link when I open the somefile.html page.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $dir = '/home/ubuntu/uisacad5.uis.edu/~rloui2/540/project2';


    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

        # We only want files
        next unless (-f "$dir/$file");

        # Use a regular expression to find files ending in .txt
        next unless ($file =~ m/\.txt$/);

        print "$file\n";
    }

    closedir(DIR);
    exit 0;
```

Comment: Ok... what's the problem? (Hint: variables don't get interpolated inside single-quoted strings.)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually asked a problem, so I can't be sure which of the issues in the code you're confused by.

I can see one obvious problem, one possible problem and a few improvements you could make.

**The Obvious Problem**

```
map  { '<a href="$_">$_</a><br>' }
```

Variables are only interpolated in double-quoted strings. This is a single-quoted string, so you're not going to get the value of `$_`, you'll just get the literal string `$_` (a dollar sign followed by an underscore).

**The Possible Problem**

It looks like this program is run once to generate a static HTML page, but you don't say how this page is then used. Is it served by a web server or do you just open it locally using a `file://` URL in your browser?

This will make a difference to what the `href` attribute in the `<a>` element needs to look like. Do you need a URL or a file path? This needs to be thought out.

**Some Improvements**

- You put newlines between your lines of output, but newlines are usually ignored by HTTP clients (like browsers). You could replace the `\n` with a `<br>` element, but it might be nicer to have a bullet list (using `<ul>` and `<li>`.
- I recommend using scalar variables for directory handles instead of barewords - i.e. `opendir my $dir_h, $dir` instead of `opendir MYDIR, $dir`.
- I don't know how much more complicated this program might get, but you will almost certainly benefit from taking the HTML out of the code and using a templating engine instead.

Comment: Hi @Dave Cross, I have added the code which retrieves the txt files in a folder and output them on a html page. I want to show each txt file as a link on the html page

Comment: @sqljavadev: If you follow the advice in my answer then you'll get a lot closer to a solution.